# Install-Package Neo4jClient wont work

Tags: c#, neo4j

im new to C# and Neo4j and want to follow this basic guide: https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/GettingStartedWithCSharp

My problem is that when i run "Install-Package Neo4jClient in the Package Manager i get an error:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Neo4jClient.3.0.0' with respect to project 'Connecter', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2'
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Neo4jClient.3.0.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving actions to install package 'Neo4jClient.3.0.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'Neo4jClient.3.0.0'
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Neo4jClient.3.0.0' does not exist in project 'Connecter'
Package 'Neo4jClient.3.0.0' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\Jakob\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Connecter\packages'
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Neo4jClient 3.0.0'. You are trying
 to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.
5.2', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files
 that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the pac
kage author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Neo4jClient
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManag 
   ement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand
```

Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Thank you

Comment: It seems your project targets _.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2_, the Neo4jClient on NuGet requires at least v4.6 ([bases off NuGet dependencies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Neo4jClient)) in order to work. Try updating the framework in your project (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx)).

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked.

Comment: I suggest to @RMH post the solution as an answer. This way jagge123 can accept it as the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your project targets .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2, the Neo4jClient on NuGet requires at least v4.6 (bases off NuGet dependencies) in order to work. Try updating the framework in your project (see here).

*Answer moved from comment so it can get accepted*